Use SlackNotifier in Airflow within a callback function
SlackNotifier works fine when called directly from the callback however is not doing anything once I call it from within a defined callback function (need to execute it only when DAG is not triggered manually). The function itself works fine (e.g. logging works). Any ideas why pls?
I have tried to use send_slack_notification() with same results. What works is SlackWebhookOperator() however that would require considerable changes (fails with multiple ERRORs right now)
def dag_run_info(**context):
    dag_run = context['dag_run']
    run_type = dag_run.run_type
    return run_type


def on_failure_callback(context):

    run_type = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_dag_run_info')

    if run_type == 'manual':
        return SlackNotifier(slack_conn_id=SLACK_CONNECTION_ID, text=SLACK_MESSAGE, channel=SLACK_CHANNEL)
    else:
        logging.info(f'No Slack notification for failed DAG because run_type:{run_type}')



"fails with multiple ERRORs right now" - Please add the errors (as text) inside the question

Should not the the SlackNotifier object be assigned to the the callback function directly as on_failure_callback=SlackNotifier(...)?
like the example in here https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/error-notifications-in-airflow#example-pre-built-notifier-slack

In the BaseNotifier implements the call protocol which makes the SlackNotifier instance invocable like a function.
This explains this example usage
 BashOperator(
        task_id="mytask",
        on_failure_callback=SlackNotifier(
            slack_conn_id=SLACK_CONNECTION_ID, 
            text=SLACK_MESSAGE,
            channel=SLACK_CHANNEL
        ),
        bash_command="fail",
    )

Since you need to send slack notifications depending on the run_type in your custom callback, you can invoke the notifier directly in your callback passing along the run context.
def on_failure_callback(context):
    run_type = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_dag_run_info')

    if run_type == 'manual':
        notifier = SlackNotifier(
            slack_conn_id=SLACK_CONNECTION_ID, 
            text=SLACK_MESSAGE,
            channel=SLACK_CHANNEL
        )
        notifier(context)
    else:
        logging.info(
            'No Slack notification for failed DAG because run_type:%s',
            run_type)


Great & most importantly functional answer, thanks Oluwafemi
